How to calculate effect sizes for predictors in lavaan regression model?
Is there a way to calculate an effect size for each predictor in a lavaan model like this?
(lavaan in this example is just used to be able to use FIML, otherwise it's a simple linear regression)
model <- sem('criterion ~ predictor1 + predictor2', data = data, missing = "FIML", fixed.x = FALSE, se = "BOOTSTRAP", bootstrap = 5000)
summary(model, standardize = FALSE, ci = TRUE, rsquare = T)


Standardized slopes are available if you switch it on in your summary().
summary(model, standardize = TRUE, ci = TRUE, rsquare = TRUE)

In the development version, you can also specifically request standardize = "std.all", so you don't have to see the std.lv solution that is irrelevant without latent variables.
